# How to make Python executable pause when it raises an error?

Tags: python

So I know I can make Python executable using `pyinstaller`.

However, every time it raises an error, it will instantly end the program, so I can't find what is the error.

I know I probably can use `time.sleep(30000)` to stop it.

But if the code raises error before it meets `time.sleep(30000)`, it will just shut down.

To sum up, how to make it keep not shutting down, so I can see where is the mistake?

Comment: use `try except` to catch the error

Comment: @haifzhan - OP wants to _see_ the error, not suppress it.

Comment: try/except does not suppress errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running the executable just by double clicking, try running it from console. For e.g. in Windows:

In cmd, run

`cd executable_path
 myexecutable.exe`

A better way would be to introduce logger so that other modules with logging implemented can write to files.

Also, you can put the code in try-except block:

```
try:
    #my_code_here
    print('Here is where the exception is')
except Exception as e:
    print('Unexpected error:' + str(e))
```

Comment: So you mean I can add whole code under try: ? I do know try and except before. But I am not sure if I can do something like this-- add whole code (maybe 1000 lines) under try.

Comment: I like your console answer which works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can put the entire code under try-except and make it to catch any exception. You can print the exception to console or put to log file or do both.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way, using Python's exception hook:

```
import sys

def myexcepthook(type, value, traceback, oldhook=sys.excepthook):
    oldhook(type, value, traceback)
    raw_input("Press RETURN. ")    # use input() in Python 3.x

sys.excepthook = myexcepthook
```

The exception hook is called whenever Python wants to print an exception. In this case, we call the previously-installed exception hook (which prints the exception), then wait for the user to press Return.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. But I don't understand how your code work. Can you explain it for me? Thank you :)

Comment: Added a bit of explanation; let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, it sounds like you are running a console program (i.e. a program with a visible console window).

If so, you have two options:

1. Run it in a console window. This simply consists of running a command prompt or terminal emulator (which comes with your computer), `cd`ing into the directory containing the program, then running it by entering the program name. When the program quits (e.g. due to an error) the traceback will be printed out and you'll be returned to the prompt.
2. You can add a `try`/`except` around your whole program that catches any errors and reports them. For example:

   ```
   try:
       main()
   except Exception:
       import traceback
       traceback.print_exc()
       raw_input("Program crashed; press Enter to exit")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just double-clicking the file, run it from the command line. A terminal window that your program automatically created will also be automatically closed when the program ends, but if you open a terminal yourself and run the program from the command line, it won't touch the open terminal and you can read the error.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `try except` like what Mars Lee said or you can do a

```
print("Test 1");
```

after a certain amount of lines.